# How to detect via Microsoft Cognitive Services if some text input is gibberish?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am building a system that looks at a user's text input and has some language recognition functionality in it. There are times obviously that the user will say something that our system does not support, maybe like, "what is the meaning of life?". We see that as a different category than an input like "as;lmdsadnklasdlkasndasldmlasd". Is there a technology on Microsoft Cognitive Services that we can use to detect if a string of input makes sense or could be considered gibberish?

Comment: I'd also like to see a solution to this. Atm I am using a data training set and experiment with ML studio but it seems like overkill and its a chore to maintain and retrain. Some of the text services claim to detect language but identify a random series of letters as english.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function that detects persay "Gibberish".  However, there is [Custom Recognition Intelligence Service](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/custom-recognition-intelligent-service-cris), which allows you to customize speech (good for accents)